# Multithreading with Async gives a TypeCasting Error when using TaskEx.WhenAll()

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await

In the code below, I am trying to execute a method, which returns a value, in another thread. However, it just DOES NOT work!!!

```
    public void main()
    {
       lstChapters.DataContext = await TaskEx.WhenAll(LoadChapters());
    }



   //CAN'T use  async in this function, it requires Task<> which
   //Error appears on the code inside []

   public [async Task<object>] Convert(object[] values, Type targetType,
     object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
   {
      dictChapters data = await IQ_LoadQuranXML.LoadChapters(TypeIndex);
   }




    internal static async Task< IEnumerable<dictChapters>> LoadChapters()
    {
        var element = XElement.Load("xml/chapters.xml");

        Task < IEnumerable < dictChapters >>  something = (Task<IEnumerable<dictChapters>>)  await TaskEx.Run(delegate
        {

        IEnumerable<dictChapters> Chapters =  
           from var in element.Descendants("chapter")
           orderby var.Attribute("index").Value
           select new dictChapters
           {
              ChapterIndex = Convert.ToInt32(var.Attribute("index").Value),
              ChapterArabicName = var.Attribute("name").Value,
              ChapterType = var.Attribute("type").Value,
           };
            return Chapters;}
        );

        return something; //An ERROR on this line
     }

    //Overriding method which does not return IEnumerable type. And it accepts index as integer.
    internal static dictChapters LoadChapters(string chIdx = "0")
    {
        int chIdxInt = Convert.ToInt32(chIdx);
        List<dictChapters> Chapters = (List<dictChapters>)  LoadChapters(); // ERROR is on this line too
        return Chapters.ElementAt(chIdxInt - 1); //index of chapter in the element starts from 0
    }
```

The Error is:

> Cannot implicitly convert type '`System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<iq_main.dictChapters>>`' to '`System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<iq_main.dictChapters>`'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

And the Other error is..

> Cannot convert type '`System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.List<iq_main.dictChapters>>`' to '`System.Collections.Generic.List<iq_main.dictChapters>`

When I cast "something" explicitly like `return (IEnumerable<dictChapters>) something` then at runtime, I get "InvalidCastException".

Comment: Could somebody please tell me the reason of the error(s)?  Also there is a discussion on the answer by Stephen, I don't understand the logic of Sync/Async. When I change my code as Stephen suggested, then I get another error, plus, The UI stops responding and the progress bar's activity  is not visible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, you'll be getting a runtime cast error earlier than that. The problem is your cast of the `TaskEx.Run` result. When you `await` something, the `Task` wrapper is removed.

```
public void main()
{
  lstChapters.DataContext = await LoadChapters();
}

internal static Task<List<dictChapters>> LoadChapters()
{
  return TaskEx.Run(delegate
  {
    var element = XElement.Load("xml/chapters.xml");
    IEnumerable<dictChapters> Chapters =  
        from var in element.Descendants("chapter")
        orderby var.Attribute("index").Value
        select new dictChapters
        {
          ChapterIndex = Convert.ToInt32(var.Attribute("index").Value),
          ChapterArabicName = var.Attribute("name").Value,
          ChapterType = var.Attribute("type").Value,
        };
    return Chapters.ToList();
  });
}
```

There are a few other problems with your code as well. Remember that enumerations like this are lazily executed. You probably want to `return Chapters.ToList();` so that the XML parsing happens on the thread pool thread.

Comment: Well, nothing has changed. Even I returned chapters.ToList()... it still takes long time to execute the IEnumerable<> code block.

Comment: And yes, it still complains about the TaskException

Comment: The Load is still synchronous (as it is in the original code)

Comment: @saafh: I fixed your type casting error. What exactly are you asking now?

Comment: Stephen - since nothing in the method calls async methods and since it's already marked async, maybe removing the Task.Run and starting the method with await Task.Yield would be simpler?

Comment: I *suspect* what he wants is it to run on a background thread.

Comment: @James well, both of you (Stephen and you) recommended that I should run the code normally/sync... I have noe removed all the async and Task.Ex things out of the code. but the UI is not responding

Comment: That's right Stephen, I want it to run on a separate thread than the UI. Also, I want to it be faster, that's the first reason to run it as async.

Comment: @saafh: Have you done what James suggested and move the `Load` into the `TaskEx.Run`? (see updated code)

Comment: Now my code is exactly as yours... Another issue... `        //Overriding method which does not return IEnumerable type. And it accepts index as integer.
        internal static dictChapters LoadChapters(string chIdx = "0")
        {
            int chIdxInt = Convert.ToInt32(chIdx);
            List<dictChapters> Chapters = (List<dictChapters>)  LoadChapters();
            return Chapters.ElementAt(chIdxInt - 1); //index of chapter in the element starts from 0
        }`

Comment: I can't run the code, as the other error is blocking it from executing. I changed the other overriding method but it doesn't help

Comment: After changing the whole chain to `async Task<dictChapters>` I am finally at a point where I can't put async and Task but I need to call LoadChapters() method...  `        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType,
          object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
           dictChapters data = IQ_LoadQuranXML.LoadChapters(TypeIndex);
        } `

Answer (score 1):

Since you did await on the TaskEx.Run, you have the enumerable coming back, not a task.

For what you're doing, I'd recommend just keeping LoadChapters as normal/sync code, then either just invoke it via Task.Run, or call it as-is.

Due to deferred execution, AFAICT your current code doesn't really help anything since you're still doing the Load synchronously.

The Task.WhenAll in main could be removed, just await LoadChapters (or whatever the asynchronous method is

Comment: OK! I have now removed the await and running the code just normally. But now, the UI gets stuck remains unresponsive or a few seconds and the progress bar doesn't show any activity.